# need to make 2 servo move wirelessly

Tags: arduino

i am using 2 arduino uno and 433MHz Rf module i'm trying to move two servo motors separately by changing potentiometer value.

But my code move the servo's together .
I want when i change the first potentiometer value the first servo move and when i change  the second thee second servo move.

This is my Transmitter Code:

```
//Transmitter Code
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch myswitch = RCSwitch();

int pot = A0;
int pot1 = A1;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    myswitch.enableTransmit(10);

}

void loop() {

    int pott = analogRead(pot);
    int pott1 = analogRead(pot1);

    int servo= map(pott,0,1024,1,180);
    int servo1= map(pott1,0,1024,1,180);

    myswitch.send(servo, 10);
    delay(200);
    myswitch.send(servo1, 10);
    delay(200);

}
```

.......................................................................

And this is my Receiver code

```
//Receiver Code:
#include <RCSwitch.h>
#include <Servo.h>

int pos = 0;

Servo myservo;
Servo myservo1;

RCSwitch myswitch = RCSwitch();


void setup() {
    myservo.attach(10);
    myservo1.attach(11);

    Serial.begin(9600);

    myswitch.enableReceive(0);

}

void loop() {
    if (myswitch.available()){
        int angle = myswitch.getReceivedValue();
        int angle1 = myswitch.getReceivedValue();

        myservo.write(angle);
        delay(200);
        myservo1.write(angle1);
        delay(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should send an identifier for the servo along with the value, this way when you receive the data you know to what servo you are referring to.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Send first a character identifying the servo. eg: '1' or '2', then send the data for that servo. In the receiver check for one of those characters and then you know that the data after them is for that particular servo.

Comment: can you show me an example of that

Answer (score 0):

Send the two values as they can be distinguishable,
like in the transmitter,

```
myswitch.send(servo, 10);
delay(200);
myswitch.send(servo1 + 1000, 10);
```

and then change the receiver

```
if (myswitch.available()){
    int value = myswitch.getReceivedValue();

    if(value > 1000) 
        myservo1.write(value - 1000);
    else 
        myservo.write(value);

    delay(200);
}
```

Comment: It's keep moving the first motor it's not stable

Comment: try removing the delay(200); statement from the receiver code and modifying
delay(200); statement in the transmitter code to delay(500);

Comment: I get the right value and then it changed and then return ... Like the two values mixed in one servo